# ADB/Intent - how to start a specific app on Android Auto?

Tags: android, auto

I'm new here and I'm trying to start a specific app on Android Auto (on the headunit) when I start driving. After driving at a specific speed I want to change the app.

Example:

- I start the engine and I want to see the musicplayer on my headunit
- After receiving a speed of 5m/s I want to change to Google Maps on my headunit

My original idea was to use the app tasker to do this job.
But I don't find a way to start a specific app on the headunit by using Android Auto. Can you please help? Is there any intent or ADB command?

Thanks a lot.

- Internet research
- Playing around with ADB and Tasker app